# How do I determine my critical hit chance in World of Warcraft against raid bosses?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Looking at my [Critial Hit Chance](https://i.gyazo.com/dc494d1312fb35a32cce9b06a89c9f01.png) I would initially think it was 33%, but hovering over it I see two different values. What do these mean?

[image]

Comment: It's different based on your target's level and some other factors (pve/pvp, ...). Raid bosses have an additional crit suppression. I don't have the exact numbers for BfA, though.

Comment: @dly Best source to read up on this crit suppression? I was unaware

Comment: Unfortunately nothing that applies to the latest expansions, that's why I couldn't post it as answer.. I'll try to back up my statement with actual numbers when I have the time to do so.

Comment: If it hasn't changed too much, there should be training dummies in major towns with various levels and types. You could target the raid training dummy and see what the tooltip says.

Answer (score 1):

> The 1st line is total value of the critical strikes from your items.
>
> The 2nd line Critical Chance you have on your current level. e.g. you
>   are level 110, then you have 21.52% chance to deal critical strike on
>   same level.